# How to split one row in different rows in TALEND

Tags: data-migration, talend

I need help to migrate one row from old DB to multiple rows in my New DB.

I have a data like:

```
OID       CUSTOMER_NAME     DOB            ADDRESS
1          XYZ              03/04/1987    ABC
```

In my new DB i am storing data in KEY VALUE pair like:

```
OID      KEY            VALUE
1      CUSTOMER_NAME    XYZ
1      DOB             03/04/1987
1      ADDRESS        ABC
```

Someone please help me how to do this using TALEND tool.

Answer (score 3):

you can use tMap multiple output linked to same output as one possible solution here. But it is not dynamic. why can you split the single row into multiple rows in source select query itself?

if you want to use this tmap option see below

tOracleInput(anyotherinput)-->tMap-->toutput/tlogrow

Take this row as input to tmap component and in tmap create one output group say out_1.
Now in this out_1 drag and link OID and CUSTOMER_NAME columns from input.
Now create another output group out_02 in this tmap and when "add a output" dialog comes
select "create join table from" and in the dropdown select out_1 group, so that our output rows from this out_02 group will also go to out_01 group. 
So our tmap will have only one output group out_01 containing rows from both out_01 and out_02. now in out_02 drag and link OID and DBO columns.
similarly repeat it for out_03 and link OID and ADDRESS column..

Comment: This is the correct solution. Thumbs up for using join tables.

Answer (score 2):

Use tSplitRow to do it. Please see below.

**Talend job:**

[image]

**output:**

[image]

Comment: check images for Job and output details

Answer (score 0):

After spending hour or two I found a solution using Talend and without writing single line of Java Code.
if you follow all my steps then you will get desire result.

Note: I took your Inputs as a source for this development, so actuals may be differed.

1. Add tMap after your Input Source.
2. concatenate source columns with coma in single column.
3. at end of concatenated columns add semicolon. see the image for more details.
   [image]

   - After tMap add tNormalize component and do setting as in image. 
     [image]
   - add tDenormalize component and and do the setting as in image. 
     [image]
4. Add tExtractDelimitedFields component and configured shown in image. 
   [image]
5. Add another tMap and do the setting as shown in image. 
   [image]
6. Now you have two output flows so add another tNormalize component for each output. 
   [image]
7. Configure first tNormalize component as shon in Image. 
   [image]
8. configure second tNormalize component with below setting, shown in image. 
   [image]
9. Our Final Job will be look like below image. 
   [image]
10. After doing all these things you will have this output
    [image]
11. Now you can create another sub job to process these output to join and create new one as per your requirement.

Comment: This seems to be too complicated for this task. The String (de)normalization itself makes this error prone to data quality issues. However I liked that you improved upon the given data model, by introducing a sequence id for the key names, but maybe you should emphasize such changes more.

Comment: You are right, but it can be done using tPivotToColumnsDelimited  component

Answer (score 0):

**tOracleInput(anyotherinput)-->tSplitRow-->toutput/tlogrow**

[Snap1](http://imgur.com/kWPA9fQ&FQbUE0S#0)

[Snap2](http://imgur.com/kWPA9fQ&FQbUE0S#1)

Comment: getting any idea from your result may be difficult

Comment: @Anptk i have attached the link for snaps

Answer (score 0):

you can use tPivotToColumnsDelimited.
Read More about it on talend Help Center.
This component will rotate your table on the basis of a row specified.
Thanks .