# How to split a column which has data in XML form to different rows of new Database as KEY VALUE in TALEND

Tags: oracle, data-migration, talend

In old DB i have a data in one column as

```
<ADDRESS>
<CITY>ABC</CITY>
<STATE>PQR</SERVICE>
</ADDRESS>
```

In my new DB i want this data to be stored in KEY VALUE fashion like:

```
USER_ID            KEY                VALUE
1                  CITY                ABC
1                  STATE               PQR
```

Someone please help me how to migrate this kind of data using TALEND tool.

Comment: Both my old and new Database are oracle

Comment: Is there a standard format for what's in the XML column?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Didn't got you what you are trying to ask. In one of my column i have values which i have mentioned in the question

Comment: Yes but does it always look like that or does the XML also have additional elements at times?

Comment: Yes it will always have values in this same format. Only values inside the child elments will get changed as per the user details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design job like below.

tOracleInput---tExtractXMLFiled---output.

1. tOracleInput component you can select XML column and make datatype as String.
2. tExtractXmlFiled component pass this XML column as " XML Filed" and set the Loop xpath Expression as "/ADDRESS"
3. Add new two Columns in output Schema of tExtractXmlFiled for city &  STATE
4. Set XPath Query in Mapping for city "/ADDRESS/CITY" and for STATE "/ADDRESS/STATE"
5. Now you have both the values in output.

See the image for more details. 
[image]

as I explain in your previous post you can follow the same approach for making Key value pair.
[how-to-split-one-row-in-different-rows-in-talend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774148/how-to-split-one-row-in-different-rows-in-talend)

Or you can use tUnpivot component as you did here.

As you said source data has Special character then use below expression to replace it.

Steps: after oracle input add tMap and use this code for replacement of special symbol

```
row24.XMLField.replaceAll("&", "<![CDATA["+"&"+"]]>")
```

once that is done execute the job and see the result it should work.

Comment: nice one :) Mine is a bit generic, and uses too much java.

Comment: Thanks a lot Umesh..i have crreated the job and its working like a charm. Though i am getting one issue while migrating one value in which i am getting '&' like in City i am getting 'And & Nic' value. Now by removing & with 'and' its working fine but with '&' i am getting    -- Error on line 1 of document  : The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. Nested exception: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.   i tried using TalendString.replaceSpecialCharForXML("row3.pivot_value") but still getting the same error. Could u plz help.

Comment: I edited my answer for special symbol handling, check it will over come your error.

Comment: @UmeshR Hey Umesh..its still giving me same error..this what i have used in tMap   row3.pivot_value.replaceAll("&", "<![CDATA["+"&"+"]]>")       i am using tMap after tUnPivotRow component

Comment: after oracle input you have to add tMap and add this expression before parsing/ tExtractXMlFiled component. can you draw your job design here

Comment: tOraclInpit--tMap--tExtractXMLFiled---tUnpivot---output. is it your job design?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68709/discussion-between-user3592257-and-umeshr).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use tJavaFlex.
[image]

Component Settings:
[image]

tJavaFlex schema:
[image]

In the begin part, use

```
String input = ((String)globalMap.get("row2.xmlField")); // get the xml Fields value
String firstTag = input.substring(input.indexOf("<")+1,input.indexOf(">"));
input = input.replace("<"+firstTag+">","").replace("</"+firstTag+">","");  
int tagCount = input.length() - input.replace("</", "<").length();
int closeTagFinish = -1;
for (int i = 0; i<tagCount ; i++) {
```

in the main part, parse the XML tag name and value, and have the output schema contain that 2 additional column. MAIN part will be like:

```
/*set up the output columns */
output.user_id = ((String)globalMap.get("row2.user_id"));
output.user_first_name = ((String)globalMap.get("row2.user_first_name"));
output.user_last_name = ((String)globalMap.get("row2.user_last_name"));
```

Then we can calculate the key-value pairs for the XML, without knowing the KEY values.

```
/*calculate columns out of XML */
int openTagStart = input.indexOf("<",closeTagFinish+1);
int openTagFinish = input.indexOf(">",openTagStart);
int closeTagStart = input.indexOf("<",openTagFinish);
closeTagFinish = input.indexOf(">",closeTagStart);
output.xmlKey = input.substring(openTagStart+1,openTagFinish);
output.xmlValue = input.substring(openTagFinish+1,closeTagStart);
```

tJavaFlex End part:

```
}
```

Output looks like:

```
.-------+---------------+--------------+------+--------.
|                      tLogRow_2                       |
|=------+---------------+--------------+------+-------=|
|user_id|user_first_name|user_last_name|xmlKey|xmlValue|
|=------+---------------+--------------+------+-------=|
|1      |foo            |bar           |CITY  |ABC     |
|1      |foo            |bar           |STATE |PQR     |
'-------+---------------+--------------+------+--------'
```

Comment: Thanks Balazs..xml value is present in one of the column of my Database table. I am not able to get how to map that column with tJavaFlex. Please help.

Comment: How to use tFlowToIterate?