# How to migrate XML elements in different column Using TALEND

Tags: data-migration, talend

I need to migrate my old data which has one column in which we dump whole XML to my new DB in which XML elemnts needs to be clumn name and corresponding value will be its value like KEY VALUE pair. My xml looks like this...

```
<ORDER_DETAIL>
 <PACK>
    <ID>703</ID>
    <NAME>iPhone 6-16 GB-Space Grey-KD 57 Pack</NAME>
    <STANDALONE_PRICE>0</STANDALONE_PRICE>
    <MONTHLY_PRICE>57</MONTHLY_PRICE>
    <UPFRONT_PRICE>0</UPFRONT_PRICE>
    <ITEMS>
       <ITEM>
          <ID>177</ID>
          <NAME>Bundle_2500_30GB_UNLIMITED</NAME>
          <ROLE>Primary</ROLE>
          <TYPE>Service</TYPE>
          <ITEM_MINUTES>2500|Local Mins.</ITEM_MINUTES>
          <ITEM_MESSAGES>Unlimited|SMS and MMS</ITEM_MESSAGES>
          <ITEM_INTERNET>30 GB|4G LTE Internet</ITEM_INTERNET>
       </ITEM>
       <ITEM>
          <ID>226</ID>
          <NAME>Gold</NAME>
          <ROLE>Primary</ROLE>
          <TYPE>SIM</TYPE>
          <NUMBER_CLASS>G</NUMBER_CLASS>
       </ITEM>
       <ITEM>
          <ID>560</ID>
          <NAME>iPhone 6 - 16 GB - Space Grey</NAME>
          <ROLE>Primary</ROLE>
          <TYPE>Device</TYPE>
          <COLOR>Space Gray|#808080</COLOR>
          <SIZE>16 GB</SIZE>
       </ITEM>
       <ITEM>
          <ID>561</ID>
          <NAME>4G LTE Hotspot - 0 GB - Black</NAME>
          <ROLE>Secondary Optional</ROLE>
          <TYPE>Device</TYPE>
          <COLOR>Black|#000000</COLOR>
          <SIZE>16 GB</SIZE>
       </ITEM>
    </ITEMS>

</PACK>
</ORDER_DETAIL>
```

Now i want to migrate this data in new tables in which in one table i need to insert data like this:

```
OID      ORDER_ID       ITEM_KEY                          ITEM_VALUE

    1          1            Service                  Bundle_2500_30GB_UNLIMITED
    2          1            Device                iPhone 6 - 16 GB - Space Grey
    3          1           If Role =              4G LTE Hotspot - 0 GB - Black
                      "Secondary Optional" 
                       then "Accessory"
```

And other elements also in other tables in this format. Someone please guide me to do this by using TALEND tool.

Comment: see my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27894211/1576196

Comment: @BalazsGunics: I am not able to get how values i need to map. How to use  tFlowTOITERATE? Could you please help.

Comment: i have created job like this:   tOracleInput---> tMap-->tExtractXMLField-->UnpivotRow--->tOracleOutput....... but i am getting data like this:    NAME||315071 ID||3150711 TYPE||3150711 ROLE||3150711 ITEM_MINUTES||3150711 ITEM_MESSAGES||3150711ITEM_INTERNET||3150711 NUMBER_CLASS||3150711SIZE||3150711 COLOR||3150711
NAME||3150711 ID||3150711 TYPE||3150711 ROLE||3150711 ITEM_MINUTES||3150711 ITEM_MESSAGES||3150711 ITEM_INTERNET||3150711 NUMBER_CLASS||3150711 SIZE||3150711 COLOR||3150711
NAME||3150711 ID||3150711 TYPE||3150711 ROLE||3150711 ITEM_MINUTES||3150711 ITEM_MESSAGES||3150711

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106808/how-to-loop-through-child-elements-of-xml-type-data-column-in-talend