# How to loop through child elements of XML type data column in talend

Tags: database-migration, talend

I want to migrate data from an old table which has one column which has data in XML form. I am trying to break the XML using talend but always getting the first element again and again.
This is the data i have in my OLD DB:

```
ID                                              DETAIL
1               <ORDER_DETAIL>
                 <PACK>
                  <ID>703</ID>
                  <NAME>iPhone 6-16 GB-Space Grey-KD 57 Pack</NAME>
                  <STANDALONE_PRICE>0</STANDALONE_PRICE>
                  <MONTHLY_PRICE>57</MONTHLY_PRICE>
                  <UPFRONT_PRICE>0</UPFRONT_PRICE>
                 <ITEMS>
                  <ITEM>
                   <ID>177</ID>
                   <NAME>Bundle_2500_30GB_UNLIMITED</NAME>
                   <ROLE>Primary</ROLE>
                   <TYPE>Service</TYPE>
                   <ITEM_MINUTES>2500|Local Mins.</ITEM_MINUTES>
                   <ITEM_MESSAGES>Unlimited|SMS and MMS</ITEM_MESSAGES>
                   <ITEM_INTERNET>30 GB|4G LTE Internet</ITEM_INTERNET>
                  </ITEM>
                  <ITEM>
                     <ID>226</ID>
                     <NAME>Gold</NAME>
                     <ROLE>Primary</ROLE>
                     <TYPE>SIM</TYPE>
                     <NUMBER_CLASS>G</NUMBER_CLASS>
                  </ITEM>
                  <ITEM>
                     <ID>560</ID>
                     <NAME>iPhone 6 - 16 GB - Space Grey</NAME>
                     <ROLE>Primary</ROLE>
                     <TYPE>Device</TYPE>
                     <COLOR>Space Gray|#808080</COLOR>
                     <SIZE>16 GB</SIZE>
                  </ITEM>
                  <ITEM>
                     <ID>561</ID>
                     <NAME>4G LTE Hotspot - 0 GB - Black</NAME>
          <ROLE>Secondary Optional</ROLE>
          <TYPE>Device</TYPE>
          <COLOR>Black|#000000</COLOR>
          <SIZE>16 GB</SIZE>
       </ITEM>
    </ITEMS>
</PACK>
</ORDER_DETAIL>
```

I am getting below output:

```
    -------------+--------------------------+--------.
|                    tLogRow_2                    |
|=------------+--------------------------+-------=|
|pivot_key    |pivot_value               |ORDER_ID|
|=------------+--------------------------+-------=|
|NAME         |Bundle_2500_30GB_UNLIMITED|3150711 |
|ID           |177                       |3150711 |
|ROLE         |Primary                   |3150711 |
|TYPE         |Service                   |3150711 |
|ITEM_MINUTES |2500|Local Mins.          |3150711 |
|ITEM_MESSAGES|Unlimited|SMS and MMS     |3150711 |
|ITEM_INTERNET|30 GB|4G LTE Internet     |3150711 |
|SIZE         |16 GB                     |3150711 |
|COLOR        |Space Gray|#808080        |3150711 |
|NUMBER_CLASS |G                         |3150711 |
|NAME         |Bundle_2500_30GB_UNLIMITED|3150711 |
|ID           |177                       |3150711 |
|ROLE         |Primary                   |3150711 |
|TYPE         |Service                   |3150711 |
|ITEM_MINUTES |2500|Local Mins.          |3150711 |
|ITEM_MESSAGES|Unlimited|SMS and MMS     |3150711 |
|ITEM_INTERNET|30 GB|4G LTE Internet     |3150711 |
|SIZE         |16 GB                     |3150711 |
|COLOR        |Space Gray|#808080        |3150711 |
|NUMBER_CLASS |G                         |3150711 |
|NAME         |Bundle_2500_30GB_UNLIMITED|3150711 |
|ID           |177                       |3150711 |
|ROLE         |Primary                   |3150711 |
|TYPE         |Service                   |3150711 |
|ITEM_MINUTES |2500|Local Mins.          |3150711 |
|ITEM_MESSAGES|Unlimited|SMS and MMS     |3150711 |
|ITEM_INTERNET|30 GB|4G LTE Internet     |3150711 |
|SIZE         |16 GB                     |3150711 |
|COLOR        |Space Gray|#808080        |3150711 |
|NUMBER_CLASS |G                         |3150711 |
|NAME         |Bundle_2500_30GB_UNLIMITED|3150711 |
|ID           |177                       |3150711 |
|ROLE         |Primary                   |3150711 |
|TYPE         |Service                   |3150711 |
|ITEM_MINUTES |2500|Local Mins.          |3150711 |
|ITEM_MESSAGES|Unlimited|SMS and MMS     |3150711 |
|ITEM_INTERNET|30 GB|4G LTE Internet     |3150711 |
|SIZE         |16 GB                     |3150711 |
|COLOR        |Space Gray|#808080        |3150711 |
|NUMBER_CLASS |G                         |3150711 |
'-------------+--------------------------+--------'
```

Getting first element of all child nodes again and again.
This is my job:
tOracleInput-->tMap>tExtraxtXMLField-->tUnPivotRow--tLogRow

Someone please help me on this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you set up "as optional loop" for your  tag in tXmlMap?

You can try to read "Items" separatly, using tExtractXmlFiled with "Loop XPATH query" : "/ORDER_DETAIL/ITEMS" and then "tFlowToIterate".
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer. I am not using tXmlMap, i am using tMap

Comment: tXMLMap is the XML "synonym" of tMap, providing the same 
functionality as tMap, but with the added ability to process XML data as well. You sould read about processing XML from "Talend Cook Book" by Rick Burton. Chapter 9, p. 160.

Comment: Thanks Max..but i resolved this in other way. Actually i was giving wrong path XPath query...i need to give "./NAME" etc and not the one i mentioned in the screenshot... :)